# VisualForce page not formatting correctly

Tags: visualforce

**Page:**

```
<apex:page Controller="RFIForm" showHeader="false">
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.StNorbertCollege_logo}"/>

<style>
    table 
    {
        border-color:#000000;
        border-style:none;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:12px;
    }
    td 
    {
        text-align:left;
        vertical-align:top;
        padding: 2px 0;
    }
    th 
    {
        text-align:left;
        background-color:#7D7D7D;
        font-size:14px;
        font-style:normal;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .small 
    {
        color:#4F4F4F;
        font-size:10px;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:italic;
    }
    .req
    {
        font-weight:normal;
        color:red;
        background-image:url('https://cwispssb.snc.edu/wtlgifs/web_required_cascade.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .header
    {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:12px;
        color:#A24C1D;
    }
    label.error
    {
        color:red;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
    input.error 
    { 
        border: 1px dotted red; 
    }


    .checkrow {vertical-align:bottom; overflow: hidden; display: block; padding: 0; margin:0; }
    .Column { width: 300px; }
    .fielderror{ border-color: red; }
    .errorBox {
            background-color: pink;
            border: 2px solid red;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            color: #CC0000;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    .errorBtn input { margin: 5px; padding: 4px 10px; }
    .errorText { margin: 5px; }
    .cell { width: 300px }
    #filedErrorBox { display: none; }


    form{ 
        margin: 10px; 
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: black;
        font-family: Verdana,Arial Narrow,helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    input, select, textarea{
        font-family: Verdana,Arial Narrow,helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
    .requiredmsgtext {
        font-family: Verdana,Arial Narrow,helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
    .label { 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Verdana,Arial Narrow,helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
    .tableHeader {
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-family: Verdana,Arial Narrow,helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .headerUnderline { background-color: #A62900; width: 100%; padding: 2px; }
    .contentText { margin-bottom: 20px; display: block; }
    #banner {  background-image: url("https://cwispssb.snc.edu/sncgifs/knightline_banner60.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 30px; }
    h1{ width: 100%; font-size: 20px; margin: 10px 0; display: block; }
</style>

<script>
function submitForm()
{
        var errorFound = false;
        $('#filedErrorBox').hide();
        $('.inputRequired').each(function() {
            if($(this).val()=='' || $(this).val()==null)
            {
                $(this).addClass("fielderror");
                errorFound=true;
                $('#filedErrorBox').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass("fielderror");
            }
        });

        $('.inputRequiredIfUS').each(function() {
            if($('select[id$=mailingCountry]').val()=='US' && ($(this).val()=='' || $(this).val()==null))
            {
                $(this).addClass("fielderror");
                errorFound=true;
                $('#filedErrorBox').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass("fielderror");
            }
        });

        $('.validDate').each(function() {
            if(validateDate($(this).val())==false)
            {
                $(this).addClass("fielderror");
                errorFound=true;
                $('#filedErrorBox').show();
            }
        });
        $('.inputRequired input.fielderror, .inputRequired select.fielderror').each(function(){$('#'+this.id.replace('_lkid','').replace(/\:/g,'\\:')).addClass('fielderror')});
        if(errorFound==false){  save(); }
        else{ alert('Please Fix the Highlighted Errors'); }
}

function validateDate(testdate) {
    var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    return date_regex.test(testdate);
}
</script>

<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:form Id="form">
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <h1>Prospect Inquiry Request</h1>
    <div class="headerUnderline"></div>
    <span class="contentText">Please enter your information in the fields below. When completed click on the <b>Submit</b> button at the bottom of page. Please allow 3 to 5 business days for processing your request for information.</span>

    <span class="req"></span><apex:outputLabel styleClass="requiredmsgtext"> - indicates a required field.</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!save}" name="save" />
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="Column">
        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="Name and Personal Data" /><apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" />
        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Student Type"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:selectList value="{!studentType}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="inputRequired">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!studentTypeOptions}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="studType"/>
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Domestic or International"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:selectList value="{!admitType}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="inputRequired">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!admitTypeOptions}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="InternationalOnly"/> 
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Student Legal First Name"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!con.firstName}" id="firstName" styleClass="inputRequired" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Student Middle Name"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!con.Middle_Name__c}" id="middleName"/>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Student Last Name"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!con.lastName}" id="lastName" styleClass="inputRequired" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Suffix"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!con.Suffix__c}" id="Suffix"/>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Nickname"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!con.Nickname__c}" id="Nickname"/>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY)"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!con.BirthDate}" id="BirthDate" styleClass="inputRequired validDate" /> 

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Gender"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.Gender__c}" styleClass="inputRequired"/>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Home Phone"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.Phone}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="International Access Code"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!intAccessCode}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Cell Phone"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.MobilePhone}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Email Address"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.Email}" styleClass="inputRequired"/>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Citizenship"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.Citizenship__c}" styleClass="inputRequired"/>        

        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="Home Address" /><apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" />
        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Street Address"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.MailingStreet}" styleClass="inputRequired"/>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="City"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputText value="{!con.MailingCity}" styleClass="inputRequired"/>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="State/Province"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:selectList value="{!con.MailingState}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="inputRequired">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!StateOptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Country"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
         <apex:selectList id="mailingCountry" value="{!con.MailingCountry}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="inputRequired">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!CountryOptions}"/>
            <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="zipCodeLable, countyLable" />
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:panelGroup id="zipCodeLable">
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Zip Code"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value="" rendered="{!con.MailingCountry=='US'}" />
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.MailingPostalCode}" styleClass="inputRequiredIfUS"/>

        <apex:panelGroup id="countyLable">
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="County"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value="" rendered="{!con.MailingCountry=='US'}" />
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.Current_County_Code__c}" styleClass="inputRequiredIfUS"/>

        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="Planning to Apply for" /><apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Desired entry Term"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:selectList value="{!interest.Desired_Entry_Term__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="inputRequired" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!desiredEntryTermOptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Desired Major"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Desired_Major__c}" />


        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="Interests" /><apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Athletic Interests"/>
            <br/>
            <div class="small">Hold ctrl to select multiple<br/>Specific sport refers to Varsity level at SNC</div>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:selectList value="{!interest.Athletic_Interests__c}" multiselect="true" size="5" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!athleticInterestsOptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Other Interests"/>
            <br/>
            <div class="small">Hold ctrl to select multiple</div>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:selectList value="{!interest.Other_Interests__c}" multiselect="true" size="5" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!otherInterestsOptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>

    </apex:panelGrid>

    <apex:outputPanel id="studType">
        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="High School Information" rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman'}" />
        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman'}" />
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="Column" rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman'}">

        <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Home Schooled"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Home_Schooled__c}" >
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolPanel"/>
        </apex:inputField>

        <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolPanel">
          <apex:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="{!interest.Home_Schooled__c==false}">

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Country"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Country__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolNamePanel"/>
        </apex:inputField>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School State/Province"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_State__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolNamePanel"/>
        </apex:inputField>

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Name"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolNamePanel">
            <apex:selectList value="{!con.High_School__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="inputRequired">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!HighSchoolOptions}"/>
                <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolOtherLabel, highSchoolOtherField" />
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolOtherLabel"><apex:panelGroup rendered="{!con.High_School__c==otherHighschoolId}">
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Other"/>
        </apex:panelGroup></apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolOtherField"><apex:inputField value="{!con.High_School_Other__c}" rendered="{!con.High_School__c==otherHighschoolId}" /></apex:outputPanel>


         <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Address"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Address__c}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School City"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_City__c}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Zip Code"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Zip_Code__c}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School GPA"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_GPA__c}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="ACT score"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.ACT_Score__c}" />

        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="HS Graduation Date" /><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
            <br/>
            <div class="small">Approximate date graduating from High School</div>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Grad_Date__c}" styleClass="inputRequired" />
        </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="Prior College Information" rendered="{!studentType=='Transfer'}" />
        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" rendered="{!studentType=='Transfer'}" />
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="Column" rendered="{!studentType=='Transfer'}">
            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College Code"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Code__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College Name"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Name__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College Address"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Address__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College City"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_City__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College State/Province"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_State_Province__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College Zip Code"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Zip_Code__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College Country"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Country__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Date Attended From"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Date_Attended_From__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Date Attended To"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Date_Attended_To__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College Degree"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_Degree__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Prior College GPA"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Prior_College_GPA__c}" />
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel id="InternationalOnly">
        <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="International Information" rendered="{!admitType=='International'}" /><apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" rendered="{!admitType=='International'}" />
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="Column" rendered="{!admitType=='International'}">
             <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Native Language"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.First_Language__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Nation of Citizenship"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Citizenship_Country__c}" />

            <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Nation of Birth"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Birth_Country__c}" />
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <div class="bottombuttons">
        <apex:commandbutton value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(); return false;" />
    </div>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

My problem is in the highSchoolPanel - it only utilizes half the pane.  It is dependent on a false value from interest.Home_Schooled__c.  How do I get it to format the width of the whole page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Looking at such a lengthy code is not easy, can you post screenshots on what is happening and what you would want the code to do?

Comment: @Rao Agreed. 1 up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the page is rendering the way it is, is because of your markup and the tag you are using.

The `apex:panelGrid` tag creates an HTML table with elements within each row up to the specified number of items per row, in your case `columns=2`.

It appears that you've either got an extra nested panelGrid tag that you don't intend or you are attempting to use an incorrect tag for the task at hand.

As you can see in your simplified markup below, there are two columns... and the highSchoolPanel is contained within the first cell of the second row of the `panelGrid`, with nothing specified to be rendered in the second cell. A panelGrid child element (rendered as a `td`) cannot span multiple columns in its row.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="studType">
<apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="High School Information" rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman'}" />
<apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman'}" />

<!-- two column table specified -->
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="Column" rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman'}">

   <!-- row 1 cell 1 -->
   <apex:panelGroup >
      <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Home Schooled"/>
   </apex:panelGroup>

   <!-- row 1 cell 2 -->
   <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Home_Schooled__c}" >
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolPanel"/>
   </apex:inputField>

   <!-- row 2 cell 1 -->
   <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolPanel">

      <!-- nested table within the first cell in the second row -->
      <apex:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="{!interest.Home_Schooled__c==false}">
         <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Country"/>
         </apex:panelGroup>
         <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Country__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolNamePanel"/>
         </apex:inputField>
         <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School State/Province"/>
         </apex:panelGroup>
[snip]
      </apex:panelGrid>
   </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

I would suggest moving the `highSchoolPanel` out of the `panelGrid` that contains it and add the `rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman'}"` to it so that it's visibility matches the other 'Freshman' items above it.

Comment: So, basically, if I make the home_schooled__c in it's own panelgrid and highschoolpanel it's own grid and render home_schooled__c on ="{!studentType=='Freshman'}" and render highschoolpanel on ="{!studentType=='Freshman'}" and home_schooled__c = false, it will fix my problem?

Comment: You will need to attempt it and find out. The key take away here is that the `apex:panelGrid` will not allow you to make one cell span multiple columns.